# RAILS: -destroy just erasing record (not deleting)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-5

**bicycle.rb**

```
  has_many :pictures, as: :imageable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :pictures, allow_destroy: true, :reject_if => proc { |obj| obj.blank? }
```

**picture.rb**

```
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
  has_attached_file :image
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png"]
```

**Edit view**

```
<% @bicycle.pictures.each do |pic| %>
              <%= bicycle_form.fields_for :pictures, pic do |frm| %>
              <div class="col-lg-2">
                  <%= image_tag pic.image.url, class: 'edit-image-thumb'%>
                  Delete: <%= frm.check_box :_destroy %>
              </div>
              <% end %>
            <% end %>
```

Picture attribute `_destroy` is whitelisted:

```
pictures_attributes: [:id, :image, :_destroy]
```

**Problem:**

As i understand, `_destroy` checkbox must delete whole record in database (picture record), but it's just erasing `image_file_name` `image_content_type` `image_file_size` column values, but record still exists.

**Explanation:**

I have **bicycle** which `has many` **pirctures**. So when i am creating new bicycle, i can attach many pictures. If i want to delete them, i am going to `edit` view and checking checkboxes for pictures i want to delete. But pictures records doesn't deleting from db, just clearing columns `image_file_name` `image_content_type` `image_file_size` leaving them blank but columns (in the same record) `imageable_type` and `id` still have values. So the image is showing up (it still exitst) but like missing (record exists but field with image name is nil)

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking for here. You're trying to destroy both records, or just the picture that's checked?

Comment: @tadman only picture. You can understand it because i'm using frm (which is picture fields) variable to generate check_box

Comment: Sure, but you're complaining specifically in your question "Bicycle - still exists" as if that's a problem.

Comment: @tadman, Bicycle - it is Imageable Type. Polymorphic association

Comment: You're going to have to explain better what the problem here is.

Comment: @tadman, ok, i'll edit my question in a minute

Comment: @tadman, edited. hope i explained my problem well at this time)

Comment: Please include the code for the controller.